# Can this code cause memory leak in android

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

I am writing a class that caches some data for multiple activities. Expectation is that the class goes through init logic once for each activity. However, it should not cause any memory leak as well.

It will be helpful if somebody could review this code for potential memory leaks. Other comments are also welcome.

```
class AbcManager private constructor(private val data : Abc) {

    fun fromAbc(a : A) : B? = data.someMethod(a)

    companion object {

        private val abcManagerCache : MutableList<AbcManagerCacheItem> = mutableListOf()

        fun of(context : Activity) : AbcManager {

            val abcManagerFromCache = attemptFromCache(context)
            if(abcManagerFromCache != null) return abcManagerFromCache
            val newData = //some operation that uses the context
            val abcManager = AbcManager(newData)
            abcManagerCache.add(AbcManagerCacheItem(
                    context = WeakReference(context),
                    abcManager = abcManager
            ))
            return abcManager
        }

        private fun attemptFromCache(context : Context) : AbcManager? {
            abcManagerCache.forEach {
                val contextFromCache = it.context.get()
                if( null!= contextFromCache && context == contextFromCache) {
                    return it.abcManager
                }
            }
            return null
        }

        private class AbcManagerCacheItem(
                val context : WeakReference<Context>,
                val abcManager : AbcManager
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `WeakReference` will most likely prevent your code from leaking here (although it depends whether `newData` has any references to the `Context` - I assume it doesn't), maintaining a collection that keeps Activities is almost never a good idea and is - more often than not - a sign of a bad design.

Especially if such collection has a static nature - like in your case. It'll live as long as your app process lives (which may be days, or longer), and it'll grow in size each time user navigates to another `Activity` or performs a configuration change. This concern can be mitigated by using `WeakHashMap`, but it doesn't make it a better architecture in any way.

In case you need to initialize `AbcManager` only once per single `Activity` instance, why not just keeping it as a field? Possibly with `by lazy` if you want to be sure you don't instantiate it before your `Activity` is in a proper state.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `WeakHashMap` and get rid of the wrapper manager class to something simpler-

```
object AbcCache {
    private val cache = WeakHashMap<Context, Abc>()

    fun putInCache(context: Activity): Abc {
        val dataFromCache = cache[context]
        if (dataFromCache != null) return dataFromCache

        val newData: T = //some operation that uses the context
        cache[context] = newData
        return newData
    }
}
```